# AWS ECS: Run Tasks Failed Reasons : ["ATTRIBUTE"]

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ecs

While trying to run a task in EC2 instances, I get this terrible error message.

```
Run tasks failed
Reasons : ["ATTRIBUTE"]
```

[Like many others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45173637/useless-amazon-ecs-error-message-when-creating-tasks), I was referred to check out the "requiresAttributes" section of my task where I found this list:

```
  "requiresAttributes": [
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-ecr-pull"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.task-eni"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.ecr-auth"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.task-iam-role"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-awslogs"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.19"
    }
  ]
```

While trying to added these seemingly useless attributes to my cluster's instances, I am blocked. The AWS console says that certain prefixes like ecs are not allowed to be customized/added.

How does one match the attributes when the platform doesn't allow it?

I've also researched into creating instances with different AMIs, but Amazon ECS doesn't allow this and simply defaults with their most recent.

Amazon ECS is a really cool product, but this reflects some of its immaturity. I actually went into ECS from a beanstalk background hoping that the professional suite would be as promised to orchestrate containers. Instead, I have a handful of reasonable complaints after using it for 3 hours!

Comment: *"While trying to added these seemingly useless attributes to my cluster's instances"*  Intuition suggests that they should be removed from the task definition rather than added to the instances.  Is that not possible?

Comment: Removing these required attributes is also impossible to my knowledge.

Answer (score 10):

I ran into this same situation trying to run a Windows docker container in ECS.

In my case, the task definition showed the following required attributes:

[image]

Describing the ECS instance with `aws ecs describe-container-instances --cluster=ClusterName --container-instances arn:<rest of the instance arn>` showed that they were missing the `ecs.capability.execution-role-awslogs` and `com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs` attributes.

The solution was documented at https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/issues/1395, and was to set the `ECS_ENABLE_AWSLOGS_EXECUTIONROLE_OVERRIDE` environment variable to `True` with the command `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("ECS_ENABLE_AWSLOGS_EXECUTIONROLE_OVERRIDE", 
$TRUE, "Machine")`. Once the `Amazon ECS` service was restarted, I could deploy my tasks.

So depending on your situation you may find there is some override that you can apply to give your ECS instances the attributes they require.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just add these attributes unless the instance and the ECS agent on the instance has that capability. For example if you aren't running a version of Docker that uses the remote API version 1.19 then if you add that attribute you are just going to break things because ECS is going to think the instance is capable of doing something because you added the attribute, but the instance is not actually capable of doing that.

My recommendation would be to use the official AMI from AWS as it already has the right combination of Docker version, agent version, operating system compatibility, and the right attributes.

Comment: "My recommendation would be to use the official AMI from AWS as it already has the right combination of Docker version, agent version, operating system compatibility, and the right attributes".

As I mentioned in the question above, I am using the default/official AMI from AWS. In fact, I even said that I was unable to change this while launching through the UI.

Comment: Considering you are quite familiar and active in the ECS community, have you ever seen developers having issues with the inability to select an AMI while creating and running a task?

Answer (score 0):

Had this today trying to create and run a Fargate task.

My issue, was that I had selected the wrong cluster. You need to create a Fargate cluster, and "Launch Type" must be set to "FARGATE".

[image]