# Configure ECS logs with windows EC2 launch type

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

When I usually run a task in ECS using Fargate, I am able to see logs in cloudwatch without any complication.

But, whenever I am trying to run task in ECS using EC2 launch type then I am getting:

```
Run tasks failed
Reasons : ["ATTRIBUTE"]
```

The strange part is when I uncheck  "Auto-configure CloudWatch Logs" using awslogs, I am able to run the task without getting any error but I don't get any logs in Cloudwatch. How can I run the task with "Auto-configure CloudWatch Logs"?

I have gone through this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/api_failures_messages.html) which pops up in the error message whenever I try to run task in my console. But, I am not getting much out of it. Also, I have gone through this old [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57390609/ecs-logs-fargate-vs-ec2) but answers are not helpful in resolving my issue.

Comment: Please check if this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51006654/aws-ecs-run-tasks-failed-reasons-attribute

Comment: Thanks Raj..I think answers mentioned in this post has been deprecated. Now, EC2 instance automatically launched with ECS cluster. User data script option can be implemented when we manually launch EC2 instance.